# What is the issue with my makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I am attempting to learn & create my first makefile for my c class assignment and I am receiving an error when I call make saying

```
gcc: error: main.o: no such file or directory

gcc: error: commands.o: No such file or directory

Makefile:13 recipe for target program failed

make: ***[program] Error 1
```

This is my makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror \
-Wfloat-equal -Wlogical-op -Wshadow -Wswitch-default \
-Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Waggregate-return \
-fno-diagnostics-show-option $(INCLUDES)

PROG = program
HDRS = commands.h faculty.h
SRCS = main.c commands.c faculty.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

$(PROG) : $(OBJS)
$(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(PROG)

main.o : main.c commands.h faculty.h

faculty.o : faculty.c faculty.h

commands.o : commands.c commands.h

    rm -f core $(PROG) $(OBJS)

TAGS : $(SRCS) $(HDRS)
    Setags -t $(SRCS) $(HDRS)
```

Inside my project folder consists of all those headers and c files but when I call the makefile, it does not create the main or the commands objects but it does create the faculty object.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Those spaces between the `-` and the flags are suspicious

Comment: I'm assuming you mean in example -Wfloat-equal -Wlogical-op, on my text editor it is properly spaced. On here, the formatting got a bit messed up. I'll edit it to represent what I exactly see.

Comment: The problem is that you've told `make` to create `commands.o` from `commands.c` and `commands.h` by removing the core, the program, and all the object files.  So, when it goes on to try linking, the object files have been removed.  Remove the line that removes the files, or put the target `clean:` on the line before, or do something to neutralize the damage wrought.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler reuploaded code using copy'n'paste. Tested the code with removing the line rm -f core $(PROG) $(OBJS) and it did create 3 object files of its respected c files. If you don't mind explaining, but when would that rm command be needed? I was only briefly taught it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the makefile contains:

```
commands.o : commands.c commands.h

    rm -f core $(PROG) $(OBJS)
```

The commands are treated as the 'action' for creating the object file from the source files, overriding the default rule that compiles an object file from a source file.

Consequently, when you try compiling `commands.o`, the program and *all* the object files are removed, leading to the complaints from `gcc` when it tries linking the program.

There are several possible fixes.  One is to remove the `rm` line altogether.  Another is to use:

```
commands.o : commands.c commands.h

clean:
    rm -f core $(PROG) $(OBJS)
```

Now the `rm` command is associated with the target `clean`, and removing the debris like that is a normal operation for a `clean` target.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jonathan's answer, if in these two lines

```
$(PROG) : $(OBJS)
$(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(PROG)
```

the second line does not start with a tab, you have another problem. Please make sure that cutting & pasting does exactly reproduce what's in your Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

The line that shows

```
$(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(PROG)
```

should be indented with one tab (not spaces, just a tab character) to be correctly parsed.

Your Makefile should read like this to compile correctly your application:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror \
-Wfloat-equal -Wlogical-op -Wshadow -Wswitch-default \
-Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Waggregate-return \
-fno-diagnostics-show-option $(INCLUDES)

PROG = program
HDRS = commands.h faculty.h
SRCS = main.c commands.c faculty.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

$(PROG) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(PROG)

main.o : main.c commands.h faculty.h

faculty.o : faculty.c faculty.h

commands.o : commands.c commands.h

clean:
    rm -f core $(PROG) $(OBJS)

TAGS : $(SRCS) $(HDRS)
    Setags -t $(SRCS) $(HDRS)
```

Use tabs (NOT SPACES, this is very important) as indentation chars, and conserve the indentation presented here. To compile, just execute

```
make
```

and to clean the project

```
make clean
```